Is it possible to realize a mechanical puzzle in between the $2\times 2\times 2$ pocket cube and the $3\times 3\times 3$ rubiks cube?
I am curious if there then exists a finite subgroup that is a proper subgroup of the $3\times 3 \times 3$ Rubik's cube group AND itself contains a copy of the $2 \times 2 \times 2$ pocket cube as a subgroup (I'll be considering quotients later, I just wanna focus on direct subgroups right now). The motivation being to create a puzzle of complexity "in between" the two.
To move the problem from real life into math. We can make the following observations:
The space of all rubiks-like mechanical puzzles can be understood to be finite subgroups of a restricted version of the space of of all area preserving continuous maps from the sphere to itself that I will call $RG^{\infty}$  (whereas $RG^{\infty}$ is generated by the set of all ways of selecting a circle on the sphere and rotating the area bounded by the circle).
The question then is does $RG^{\infty}$ contain a finite subgroup strictly between the pocket cube and the rubiks cube.
With this translation it's still not immediately obvious for me how to proceed.

You could take a 3x3x3 and peel off the stickers of the edge pieces so that you get a 2x2x2 with centres. Or you could peel off the stickers of the centres instead to get a void cube. These are the two most obvious intermediate puzzles, but there are lots of groups inbetween that do not make for nice puzzles because they do not share generators with the 2x2x2 and 3x3x3. For example, take the subgroup of 3x3x3 permutations that keep the four U layer edge pieces fixed.

This is actually really clever. A lot of different groups could be made by cleverly deleting stickers and or making stickers the same.
